# copy in non-sequential columns vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm passing data from one table to another, the columns match but in table 2 they are not sequential, I have some columns in the middle.

The code below copies and pastes in the sequential columns, how can I add one more condition to check if the headers are the same before pasting?

[image: exemple from my tables]

```
Sub NewNameandCostCenter()

  Dim start As Double
  start = Timer

  Dim countOfChangedRows As Long

  'set rngMap array
  Dim rngMap As Range
  Set rngMap = Worksheets("Lançamento captação").Range("A3:g4")

  'set rngData array
  Dim rngData As Range
  Set rngData = Worksheets("Base balanço Hídrico").Range("a6:k800")

  Dim aMap As Variant
  aMap = rngMap.Value

  Dim aData As Variant
  aData = rngData.Value

  Dim mapRow As Long
  Dim datarow As Long
  Dim mapcol As Long

  For mapRow = LBound(aMap, 1) To UBound(aMap, 1)
    For datarow = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
      'Check the key matches in both tables
      If aData(datarow, 1) = aMap(mapRow, 1) Then
        countOfChangedRows = countOfChangedRows + 1
        'Assumes the columns in map and data match
        For mapcol = LBound(aMap, 2) + 1 To UBound(aMap, 2)
          aData(datarow, mapcol) = aMap(mapRow, mapcol)
        Next mapcol
      End If
    Next datarow
  Next mapRow

  rngData.Value = aData

  Debug.Print countOfChangedRows & " of "; UBound(aData, 1) & " rows updated in " & Timer - start & " seconds"

End Sub
```

This code finds the correct line but copies it in sequence, I need to check it column by column before pasting

Comment: you will need to copy column by column and not the whole.  The you will need to use `Find` or `Application.Match` to find the column in which to assign the data.

Comment: Would you have an example to clear my mind? This code was the one that came closest to what I have been looking for, I haven't found any other until then.

Comment: Using match on the first row of a table will give you a number indicating the relative position of the header in that table.